# What to call this style of chinese teapot/winepot handle?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

I have tried to baidu and google, both english and chinese for the name of this style handle.  I cannot find it-- I am able to find the handle in results of generic searches but I am sure it must have a name to specifically find it.

I could not find it in any guides for general teapot shapes etc either.  Any detailed resources for those less common porcelain and ceramics shape/style/parts would be wonderful too--> but totally optional to answer the question.  Thanks (๑˃̵ᴗ˂̵)

The exact style in question:

[image]

Comment: maybe, try “ x 形高提梁”, or “提梁壺” 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 those are some of the generic terms already tried.  The best results come from just generically searching the style of teapot, 清花提梁壺.  This does not at all help address the specific handle style unfortunately.  I appreciate the attempt though                         \_(:3」z)_

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, I am looking specifically for these arch/bridge shaped handles vs round or square generic ones.  It is such a distinct style thats been around for so long I know it must have a term.  I just am failing to search it up properly, with muddied results of other stuff mixing in.

Answer (score 1):

i think this style is called “提梁壺”, roughly means “lifting roof beam kettle”

that the handle of the kettle is like a roof beam, above the kettle body

further, it’s “硬提梁”, that the handle is made together with the body (硬提梁是與壺身同時制出), same material

here’s a page about this style, in simplified chinese:

https://www.taohuren.com/huxing/tilianghu.html

some “similar” style kettles:

[明 隆慶 青花雲龍紋提梁壺](https://theme.npm.edu.tw/opendata/DigitImageSets.aspx?sNo=04014387)

[明 萬曆窯 青花六稜提梁壺](https://catalog.digitalarchives.tw/item/00/0c/c3/2e.html)

have fun :)